# NodeJS - Which layer should I roll back the transaction with multiple inserts?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, architecture

I'm using Controller Layer/Service Layer/Repository Layer in my API with Postgres database (I'm using node-postgres).

In a given service, before inserting certain information A, I need to insert other information in other tables in the database. However, if there is a problem with one of the inserts, I would like to roll back the transaction. In node-postgres, rollbacks are done as follows:

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
;(async () => {
  // note: we don't try/catch this because if connecting throws an exception
  // we don't need to dispose of the client (it will be undefined)
  const client = await pool.connect()
  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')
    const queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
    const res = await client.query(queryText, ['brianc'])
    const insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO photos(user_id, photo_url) VALUES ($1, $2)'
    const insertPhotoValues = [res.rows[0].id, 's3.bucket.foo']
    await client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues)
    await client.query('COMMIT')
  } catch (e) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK')
    throw e
  } finally {
    client.release()
  }
})().catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

The database connection is called on the Repository Layer. However, the rollback situation will only happen on the Service Layer. How do I solve this situation, since for architectural reasons, I can't call the database connection directly in the Service Layer? Is there a problem with my architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to put all the related transactions into a single method in your repository layer.  This is generally "OK" because they are all fundamentally a single transaction.

If you need to support distributed transactions, you are better off using a [unit of work pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to implement holding onto the various transactions, and rolling back on the whole unit of work.

Comment: Does this work if the various insertions of other information into your tables depended on whether a piece of information exists or not?

Ex.: I have the Product table and the Items table. If the Product already exists, you do not need to insert it, otherwise insert it. And after that, with the product id, I enter information in Items.

Does it make sense to merge this kind of rule into a Repository Layer?

Comment: Yup, it all has to do with data storage/retrieval details.  Don't put business logic in, but pure database-logic is just fine.  Think about if you were storing it in some other storage medium that had something like a JSON file-store instead of a RDMS, you would not need to extract the multi-table logic outside the repository...  Also, just a FYI, take a look at upsert instead of insert/update logic: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: Nice! I believe this will be enough for my problem. Thanks a lot for the help!